# Members last visit zoo visitor

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, status, low-alphabet

I'm trying to display all the data of my members, including the last time they logged in (last visit), but I can't seem to get the right data. Either I receive the data of the users that's currently logged in, or nothing at all. I'm currently trying this:

```
Last visit

{exp:low_alphabet:entries
        channel="members"
        status="Members-id5"
    }
    {exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{entry_date}"}{last_visit format="%Y %m %d"}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
{/exp:low_alphabet:entries}
```

I thought this should work since this is the way it's being described here: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/member/#member-profile-templates

Does anyone has the idea what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it turned out to be:

```
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="members"
        dynamic="no"
        status="Members-id5|Super_Admins-id1"
    }
        {exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{author_id}"}
           {last_visit format="%d %m %Y"}
        {/exp:member:custom_profile_data};
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```